# how to count the number of rows in derived table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tables

```
emp (id , name)
cust(id, name)
```

Now i want number of rows in the result of

```
q=select emp.id  from emp,cust where emp.id not in (select id from cust);
```

For this
I am posing query:

```
select count(*) 
from (select emp.id  
      from emp,cust 
      where emp.id not in (select id from cust));
```

But i am getting an error:

> Every derived table must have alias name"

What is the correct query to count the rows in the result of q?

Comment: Please consider marking an answer (checkbox below the votes) if one of these helped you.  Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

USE AN ALIAS;

```
 select count(*) from 
    (
     select emp.id from emp where emp.id not in (select id from cust)
    )A;
```

Comment: Excellent answer, though your formatting (caps, code alignment) could use some work. ;-) +1

Answer (score 1):

@vjhil's answer is correct, but I believe that your query could be greatly simplified to:

```
select count(*)
from
  emp
where
  emp.id not in (select id from cust)
```

Or further to:

```
select count(*)
from
  emp e
  left join cust c on e.id = c.id
where
  c.id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Put an alias in front of subquery and try executing.

```
select count(*) from (select emp.id from emp,cust where emp.id not in (select id from cust)) a;
```